# C# DBContext doesn't exist after executing some long tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, rest, post, domain-driven-design

First of all I have to say that I'm not sure if I'm coding the proper approach, I'll first explain what I'm trying to do.

1. Receive POST request to create a new RawTask.
2. Insert the RawTask in its DB table and a related register in ProcessedTask table.
3. Execute some long tasks (inside Thread.Task)
4. Update the ProcessedTask with the feedback of the previous point.

Doubts/Problems

1. The first problem is that the DBContext doesn't exist when the task finishes its execution. So it's impossible to update the processedTask.
2. The insertedTask.ExecuteScript() is well placed at TaskController/POST method?
3. Is it a good approach to create and update the ProcessedTask entity in the POST method of this Task Controller?

Here's some code to explain it better.

```
public class RawTaskController : ControllerBase
        {
            private readonly ICrudService<RawTask> _rawTaskCrudService;

            private readonly ICrudService<ProcessedTask> _processedTaskCrudService;

            public RawTaskController(ICrudService<RawTask> taskCrudService, ICrudService<ProcessedTask> processedTaskCrudService)
            {
                _rawTaskCrudService = taskCrudService;
                _processedTaskCrudService = processedTaskCrudService;
            }

            [HttpPost]
            public async Task<IActionResult> AddTask([FromBody] RawTaskModel rawTask)
            {
                insertedRawTask insertedRawTask;
                ProcessedTask processedTask = new ProcessedTask();

                try
                {
                    //Initialize some fields
                    rawTask.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                    rawTask.DateReg = DateTime.Now;

                    //Insert the received task after mapping the model.
                    insertedRawTask = await _rawTaskCrudService.Add(rawTaskMapper.Map(rawTask));



                    if (insertedRawTask != null)
                    {
                        //Initializing the new processedTask
                        processedTask.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                        processedTask.IdRawTask = insertedRawTask.Id;
                        processedTask.DateReg = DateTime.Now;
                    }

                    //Insert the processedTask after getting some fields from RawTask.
                    ProcessedTask insertedProcessedTask = await _processedTaskCrudService.Add(processedTask);


                    if (insertedProcessedTask != null)
                    {
                        //Here comes the long executiong, for example a HDD defrag (some hours)   
                        Task task = new Task(async () =>
                        {
                        //The behaviour of the execution is defined in the domain class Task
                        if (insertedRawTask.ExecuteScript())
                            {
                            //If the execution was succesful we will update the processedTask created before
                            insertedProcessedTask.State = "Finished";
                                await _processedTaskCrudService.Update(insertedProcessedTask);
                            }
                        });
                        task.Start();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return StatusCode(500);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return StatusCode(500);
                }
                return Ok(insertedRawTask);
            }
        }
```

I would appreciate any other possible solutions to accomplish this kind of behavior.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Request-extrinsic code is dangerous; a proper solution is to use a durable queue with a background processor](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2021/01/asynchronous-messaging-1-basic-distributed-architecture.html). There are ***very*** few scenarios where just throwing a task on the thread pool is an appropriate solution.

> The first problem is that the DBContext doesn't exist when the task finishes its execution. So it's impossible to update the processedTask.

Background processors need their own `DbContext`.

I generally recommend the background processor be a completely separate *process* - Azure Function, Win32 Service, etc.

Comment: Tha's extactly what I was looking for. 
Maybe it's worth to create a service with SignalR looking for changes in RawTask table and perform X actions. Or call another separate process directly in the POST request.

Thanks for your response Stephen.